# How to add Link or Anchor within the Same Note in Evernote

Tags: evernote

I know it's possible to add Link to a different Note within Evernote. Like [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3975/can-i-link-between-notes-in-evernote/8503) or [this](https://blog.evernote.com/blog/2015/01/16/use-note-links-connect-essential-content-evernote/).

However, I want to add Link within the same Note. So that I can click and jump to another part of the same note. The result should be the same as hash tagged links within HTML, like: `http://link/to/page/#Hash_Tag_Anchor`

Is this possible in an Evernote note?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [ELIN](https://github.com/CoreParadox/EvernoteLinkInNote/releases), which works. It's a third party program, but at least it gets the job done.

I found it via the [forum](https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/83621-create-jump-links-in-your-notes-with-elin/).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Even though the project is discontinued by the author, still, I could figure out the HTML required for the jump links from the source CODE.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work on mac.
In general, the interface between mac and windows is really inconsistent.

Comment: I could figure out how to do it on Mac. Obviously the Windows app will not work for Mac, however, the HTML CODE inside the app works for Mac as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement HTML-like anchor links by breaking down the sections you want to link to into separate notes.

You can then place links to those sub-notes as a table of contents in your main note.

You can find a video demo of the solution in [this blog post](https://blog.devgenius.io/navigating-within-a-note-html-like-anchor-tags-in-evernote-1ceb93779d2).